# full CNN model Classification Bias to specific Class

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a full CNN model. its output's shape is (16,16,5) and its activation is softmax.
I need to classify each cell Separately, one class is for background and the other for each object's class ( 4 + 1 ).

for example for 3*3 output my desire output is like this

[image]

because of background class is more repetitive, my model bias to class 0 (background ). what should I do for this imbalance classification.
I'm using TensorFlow and Keras for this. And my Base Model is Resnet50

thank you a lot

Comment: Could you show an example of how you have generated the training dataset?

Comment: I Add a Picture. I think it can help you. my project is something like an "I'm not a robot" captcha. I assign a class to each cell that contains the object of that class.

Comment: I understand what you want to achieve, but I would like to look at what your training dataset looks like so that I can the see possible "error".

Comment: my training dataset is from https://www.kaggle.com/c/severstal-steel-defect-detection. but I changed labels from mask to grid classification

Answer (score 0):

An easy and usually successful approach is to use weighting factors for each class in the sum of which the loss consists. The factor can be the inverse of the class sizes, or somewhere between that and `1`.

For example, for a class ratio of 100:1, usually a reweighting of 1:100 or 1:10 works well.

Comment: may you give me an example code for the loss function? considering that my output is a 4d tensor with shape (batch, cell count, cell count, class )

Comment: @amirhossein_mlkz If you use cross-entropy, instead of `loss=sum(cross_entropy(output,output_target))`, use `loss=sum(cross_entropy(output,output_target)*reweighting)`, where `output`, `output_target` and `reweighting` all have the array size you mentioned, `cross_entropy` and `*` work elementwise, and `sum` works across all dimensions of its input array.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am still waiting to see the training dataset, I would say that in principle I would work with only four classes, car, motorcycle, truck and bicycle (I have invented them). That is to say, I would not have a fifth class that would be the background, but I would get this last one by discarding.

If the percentage of possibility is less than X, we discard the four possible classes and say that it is the background.

Still, it is important that if you follow this method, your training dataset does not have only images of cars, motorcycles, etc. in its entirety. You must have trained yourself to recognize the vehicles in pieces.

Another interesting option would be to preprocess the image, join the X pieces that compose the image, apply the NN directly to the image and then transfer the results to the different frames (maybe here you need to apply other types of NN such as segmentation).

I hope I have been helpful, if you expand the information we can try to help you together.

Comment: If I remove the background class, can it cause my model accuracy to decrease and my False Positive to increase?   another question, can you explain your purpose for preprocessing the images? in my project, I process all cells in one forward in the model and the classification of the cells is returned as a 16x16x5 tensor for the whole image.